# subsection command not working in elsevier LaTeX template

Tags: latex

I am working on Elsevier template with a single column format, I am facing an issue with subsections command not working as they are displayed like a normal section with wrong numbering, for example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
\subsubsection{BB}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output is like this. All sections with no subsection numbering.]

Can anyone help me on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're using it properly. This must be an issue with your class file (`cas-sc`) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is by design (which would be a very odd behaviour), but this behaviour is caused by some redefinition in the class file. To workaround this problem one could fix these redefinitions and use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {10pt \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 2\p@}%
    {.1\p@}%
    {%\let\@hangfrom\relax
     \ssectionfont\raggedright }}

\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {10pt \@plus 1\p@ \@minus .3\p@}%
    {.1\p@}%
    {%\let\@hangfrom\relax
     \sssectionfont\raggedright}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
\subsubsection{BB}
\end{document}
```

(don't do this if you intend to submit the document to the journal)